# Chat Application with Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, chat

I want to build a basic chat application which includes location sharing. I proficient enough in Java, but haven't worked enough on Android Platform. How do I approach this problem and what are the steps to be taken?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid that this question is too vague. What is it exactly that you are having problems with? The chat part? The maps part? The integration? Tooling? The Dev Process per se? What errors are you encountering? Please update your question with more details. Thanks alot and have a great day! :)

Comment: I dont know where to start. Should I start with the chatting part and then integrate maps. In the chatting part what should I be looking for and where should I learn from

Answer (score 0):

Send location values latitude and longitude to the other person via chat message. You can get user's last known location by:

```
private double[] getGPS()
{
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

    /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop */
    Location l = null;

    for (int i = providers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if (l != null)
            break;
    }

    double[] gps = new double[2];
    if (l != null)
    {
        gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
        gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
    }
    return gps;
}
```